# Convert the power series solution of $(1+x^2)y''+4xy'+2y=0$ into simple closed-form expression

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(a)$Use two power series in $x$ to find the general solution of
$$(1+x^2)y''+4xy'+2y=0$$

and state the set of $x$-values on which each series solution is valid.

$(b)$ Convert the power series solutions in $(a)$ into simple closed-form expressions.

$(c)$ Use $(b)$ to find the general solution of the equation above on the whole real line.

For $(a)$, I used  $y(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$,and solved the recurrence relation to be $a_{2k} = (-1)^ka_0$ and $a_{2k+1} = (-1)^ka_1$, where $a_0$ and $a_1$ are arbitrary.

And for the solution I got $y(x)=a_0\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^kx^{2k} +a_1\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^kx^{2k+1}$.

How do I convert the solution into simple closed-from expressions, and how should I solve $(c)$?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Your power series are both geometric series.

Comment: I don't understand why they are geometric series?

Comment: The terms (in both) each have a ratio of $(-x^2)$

Comment: I got $y(x) = \dfrac{a_0}{1+x^2} +\dfrac{a_1x}{1+x^2}$, is that right? And what does it mean by "general solution on the whole real line"?

Comment: That would be right if your sums started with $k=0$, but you've written that they start from $k=1$ (which I think might be a typo).    Note that the power series only converge for $\left| x \right| < 1$ (plus whatever happens at the boundary), s0 it does not define a solution everywhere.  A pirori, you only know that the function you've found satisfies the differential equation in that region.  Show that it actually works everywhere, either by using a theorem or just plugging it back into the differential equation.

Comment: What doe "pirori" mean?

Comment: I plugged $y(x)$ back into the differential equation, which solved the differential equation. Does this mean $y(x)$ is a general solution on the whole real line?

Comment: Yes it does, because $y(x)$ is a working solution defined everywhere, while the power series was not.  Knowing something "a priori" means before you've done anything, before proof or experience can further shape your knowledge.  So by the time you came up with $y(x)$ you *a priori* knew that it was a solution to the differential equation where the power series was defined, but you could not say it was a solution anywhere else without a further argument or verification.  The term is [latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori).